# XML-Warnings don´t show up in Studio 17 with ReSharper 18.2

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2017, schema, resharper

i´ve got about 1000 xml´s with a specified scheme in my Solution. They are used as Model in the MVVM-Pattern. I expand the scheme, so in every XML the name-attribute of an element will be unique. If i open up a XML with dublicated names, i can see, the Location of the duplicated Name is marked.

My Problem is, that the marked name isn´t recogniezed as a warning or error. 
I can´t figure it out, how to Show this warnings in the Solution-Error-Window from ReSharper. I checked all the Options under "Inspection Severity" but i can´t find the issue.

Thanks for  you´re help.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is Run an Inspection:

On Resharper 2018.2.3

Resharper > Inspect > Code Issues in Solution